# How to reduce the apk size in expo project?

Tags: javascript, react-native, apk, expo, android-install-apk

I'm developing my APK via Expo. expo start and then exp build:android in cmd. My APK size is 45MB when I download it to phone, but when APK is installed it is 48MB. How is this possible? Can I reduce apk size?

Thanx in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in progressing request. You can upvote request from [this link.](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/reducing-app-size)